# The correct way of implementing getItemId() in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have generic class

```
public abstract class BaseAdapter<T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
  private List<T> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
  //other override methods

  @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to implementing getItemId()? I think that `return position` like in many example is not correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Create a base interface that has a method that returns a type `long`
   eg.

   ```
   interface BaseInterface{
       long getId(); 
   }
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   abstract class BaseAdapter<T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter
   ```

   to

   ```
   abstract class BaseAdapter<T extends BaseInterface> extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
   ```

   Note: The signature changed to `T extends BaseInterface`
3. Replace

   ```
   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return itemsList.get(position).getId();
   }
   ```

Comment: itemsList has type <T>. And has only default lists methods

Comment: and itemsList.get(position).  has objects methods

Comment: The Google I/O app itself returns position as fallback, I wonder if this is OK https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/e4364eec0d8f358215aee30cce2b4836ec169b5a/lib/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/myio/MyIOAdapter.java#L93

Comment: What about `hashCode()` instead of `getId()`?

Comment: `hashCode()` implementation cannot be enforced. If an interface forgets to implement it, it will not throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

In the List you could only return the Id of the Item available at specific row as mentioned by Google documents:

> getItemId
>
> Get the row id
>   associated with the specified position in the list.

But that's not the case with RecyclerView, in RecyclerView you have to ensure that you either return a unique Id for each Item or In case of no Stable Id you should return `RecyclerView.NO_ID` (-1). Please Refrain from returning values that are not stable. (An Stable value would be a unique value that does not change even if position of dataset changes)

Comment: Exactly, the behavior of [getItemId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemId(int)) in RecyclerView.Adapter differs from [getItemId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItemId(int)) in ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

you should implement this methode:
as you see you must tell the Adapter that you implemented that by `setHasStableIds(true);`

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
MyAdapter() {
    setHasStableIds(true); // **very importent**
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // requires unique value, it means need to keep the same value
    // even if the item position has been changed.
    return mItems.get(position).getId();
}
```

}

Comment: can you explain why this code gives a static value? to me it looks like `mItems.get(position)` returns an instance of your model class , which has a a function returning some integer id. why would your model return the same id again and again? If you are using dbs or network, then usually the `id` is unique and `getId()` returns a unique value everytime

Comment: You're right. By "static" I mean unique value for each item. Not a same value.

Comment: Then please change the word `static` to `unique` , as this gives a totally different meaning, and newbies like me spend 10 minutes on this answer to get even more confused :P