# Accessibility focus lost while deleting items in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility

I am new to accessibility workarounds in android, please help me fix the issue with losing focus while deleting any item from recycler view. I used the code below for this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Override method getItemId(), give a stable id to each item:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Set has StableId:

```
adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
```

Now basically you can keep focus in a concrete item when call notifyDatasetChange, if not, disable animator：

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42664630/9522268)

But it's not working. I just need the way around how we can keep the focus after deleting the item from recycler view. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the getItemId() function that you have overridden?

Comment: its same as mentioned before i have return the same  return position; in getItemId()

Comment: I think the problem may be that you are not returning an unique value for the item in the list. Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42647044/7877039